# The equivalent of "kubectl get crds" in golang

Tags: go, client-go, kubernetes-go-client

If I want to list namespaces on the cluster using client-go I can use a simple command to do this:

```
clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces().List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
```

And what would the equivalent of the `kubectl get crd` command look like?
Is this even possible to do?

I tried to find a solution, but most of the answers I found answered how to query a specific crd, rather than get a list of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApiextensionsV1beta1 API is part of the apiextensions-apiserver library, not the kubernetes library.To access the ApiextensionsV1beta1 API, you will need to import the apiextensions-apiserver library, as follows:

```
import (
    apiextensionsclientset "k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/pkg/client/clientset/clientset"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
clientset.ApiextensionsV1beta1().CustomResourceDefinitions().List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
```

This API returns a list of CustomResourceDefinitions objects.

Comment: clientset.ApiextensionsV1beta1 undefined (type *kubernetes.Clientset has no field or method ApiextensionsV1beta1)

Comment: responded in answer section @samuelus